# Does page table changes with context switch?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, scheduler, virtual-memory, tlb

Suppose, the page table changes with each processes then we don't require TLB and memory for page table. We can implement it with some reasonable number of registers. But the galvin book says(not precisely but my interpretation) we have an entry in page table all pages and we have separate table for each processes so we are using pointer to refer a particular table. 
Am I correct(understanding from the book)?
If then what is the need to change the page table for each context switch?

Answer (score 2):

if we are arguing that we can use one page table for whole system then simple answer to this question is that using page table/process provides more security by providing memory isolation among processes running on same system. each process has its own page table means it can not interfere with other processes memory. page table management can not be achieved through registers due to size and number of page tables. suppose you want to have extra registers to store active page tables still you will need memory to store back inactive page tables this is equally expensive method(for your first line). I suggest you to spend some time on understanding of present hardware facilities and OS functionalities then try to come up with innovation in design otherwise you will remain astray from learning.

your Op title ask "does page table changes with context switch" YES page table changes on context switch